# Memsql start with a password and recover previous data on docker volume

Tags: docker, singlestore

How can I start a memsql cluster with a pre-specified password?

I had a memsql container running (from `memsql/quickstart` image).
The container is not running now (because of server restart) and I have removed the stopped container.

The password was changed using `memsql-update-root-password`

I also had `/memsql` folder mounted as a volume (so all the data is saved).

Now directly running the image again with the volume mounted on the location `/memsql` does not allow the MASTER node to start up probably because it is expecting the old password.

`ERROR: ProcessHandshakeResponsePacket() failed. Sending back 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Is there some way I can start a new memsql cluster and not lose my old data?

Comment: What error are you seeing when memsql does not start up?

Comment: `ProcessHandshakeResponsePacket() failed. Sending back 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: That error means that login didn't work because whoever is trying to connect is not using the correct password, but it doesn't mean the node failed to start up. Are you able to connect to it with the new password?

Comment: I think that the error is for the MASTER node itself. The error gets logged continuously and does not stop.

Comment: I managed to sort out the problem with a little hack. Started a new memsql container with a different volume (say vol_new). It starts successfully (because no other password was set ever, its a fresh container and empty volume). Then I change the password for the MASTER node to the one I had on earlier container. Stopped the container. Copied over the "_data" folder (on host) of old volume to "_data" folder of vol_new (on host). Started the container. MASTER node starts successfully and all my previous data is there.